# How to Install the Ada gnatcoll-db library on Linux Enviromet (Centos 7)

Tags: linux, postgresql, ada, gnat

Today I have attempted to install the gnatcoll library on my Linux machine - Centos7 . I have downloaded the library from here: https://github.com/AdaCore/gnatcoll-db

I want to use Postgres for my database: https://github.com/AdaCore/gnatcoll-db/tree/master/postgres

So, I have attempted to use the Postgres make file. I have opened the Postgres folder within Terminal and then attempted to build the Makefile.

```
gnatcoll_postgres.gpr      gnatcoll-sql-postgres-builder.adb  gnatcoll-sql-postgres-gnade.ads  Makefile
gnatcoll-sql-postgres.adb  gnatcoll-sql-postgres-builder.ads  gnatcoll-sql-ranges.adb          postgres_support.c
gnatcoll-sql-postgres.ads  gnatcoll-sql-postgres-gnade.adb    gnatcoll-sql-ranges.ads          README.md
[parallels@localhost postgres]$ make Makefile
make: gprconfig: Command not found
Makefile:71: *** No toolchain found for target "x86_64-redhat-linux".  Stop.
[parallels@localhost postgres]$ make -f /home/parallels/Desktop/gnatcoll-db-master/postgres/Makefile
make: gprconfig: Command not found
/home/parallels/Desktop/gnatcoll-db-master/postgres/Makefile:71: *** No toolchain found for target "x86_64-redhat-linux".  Stop.
[parallels@localhost postgres]$
```

Please can anyone share anylight as to why I am unable to make this file. Is there something I need to do, prior to attempting this?

Any guidance would be massively appreciated.

Thank you

Comment: Have you installed gprbuild? I think gprconfig is part of it. and Make couldn't find that.

Comment: /usr/bin/gprconfig is provided by the package `gprbuild`. Depends on package `xmlada`.